# Java: How much memory a reference implies?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, reference

As the question says, how much memory is used for a reference to an Object in the Java Programming Language?

Please, if you have a trusted source is better.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-con

Comment: @khachik thanks! I've been looking, but didn't found it. Anyway, i think that dty an the other guys wrote about interesting things that are not present in the other question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not specified by the language or JVM spec. However, it's generally accepted that any sane implementation will be 4 bytes on a 32-bit machines and between 4 and 8 bytes (depending on compressed pointer settings, etc.) on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: A referencer also implies a referee, the object referred to takes at least 16 bytes in Sun Java 6 and is a multiple of 8 bytes in size.

Comment: Yes but two references does not imply two referees ;-)

Comment: @aioobe, true, they have to be counted separately, but in the simplest cases they are not. A null reference doesn't use any additional memory.