# Object reference or identifier decision when a new dependency is needed

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-security

I need to make a decision to keep only identifier of another class or an object reference to it within another class. The situation is as follows:

```
public class Article {
    private int ownerId;
}
```

or:

```
public class Article {
    private User owner;
}
```

And here comes the problem:

1. I have separated my domain classes into another module (say `domain`, and the rest of the project is in `core`), this is because this `domain` module can be imported by some users ([Drools Workbench](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR3/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html) users who design processes)
2. The `Article` class is in the `domain` module.
3. `domain` module is not dependent on Spring security, but the `core` is.
4. If I will use an object reference in `Article` I will have to include Spring Security as a Maven dependency to `domain` module (because `private User owner` is a Spring Security `User`), which will make it significantly greater in size.
5. I don't quite want my `domain` module to be a big jar file, because it makes it hard to include in [Drools](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.2.0.CR3/drools-docs/html/wb.Workbench.html), or even more around within company.

So, what might be the correct way to go in this situation? Normally, I would go for the object reference for the obvious reasons that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596430/java-object-reference-or-identifier?lq=1) as well, but I am inclined to make an exception for this case.

Comment: This is just an opinion and I do not know if it suits you, but I would separate the `core` project into two projects, one with the classes that do not need the Spring Security, and other with the ones that need it (and maybe call it `core-spring`).

Comment: @JaviFernández The problem is not in `core` but in `domain`. I can separate `domain` into two `domain` and `domain-spring`, but then again it wouldn't help a lot since `domain-spring` requires Spring Security and ends up as quite a fat jar. Did I get you correctly?

Comment: Sorry Hasan, I think I didn't explain myself correctly. What I mean is that you can separate the `core` project into two projects (for example `core` and `core-spring`), and the project `domain` would only include de `core` project as dependency. In this way you have three projects: `core`, `core-spring` that depends on `core`, and `domain` which also depends on `core`. The `core` project would contain only the common code for `core-spring` and `domain` projects.

Comment: Oh I see, it's just naming that confused me. In my case, `core` depends on `domain` since it's the module with services etc. and `domain` is just a jar to be imported in Drools. I understand you now, it's a similar solution to the one in answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution can be found extending the Article domain object in the package you need, attaching to extended version the information you need (a sort of Decorator)

Comment: You mean I can extend `Article` in `core` to attach `private User owner` to it?

Comment: Yes, because in the core module you need something that has some other informations related to the base class