# Memory footprint of int[] and Integer[] arrays

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

I try to create an array of Integers (i tried with own object but the same happened with int) , with size of 30 million. i keep getting "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"

```
Integer [] index = new Integer[30000000];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 30000000 ; i++){
    index[i] = i;
}
```

i checked the total heap space, using "Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()" and "maxMemory()"
and saw that i start with 64 MB and the max  is 900+ MB, and during the run i get to 900+ on the heap and crush.

now i know that Integer takes 4 bytes, so even if i multiply 30*4*1000000 i should still only get about 150-100 mega.

if i try with a primitive type, like int, it works.

how could i fix it ?

Comment: run the program with more heap memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java's int primitive will take up 4 bytes but if you use a ValueObject like Integer it's going to take up much more space. Depending on your machine a reference alone could take up 32 or 64 bits + the size of the primitive it is wrapping.

You should probably just use primitive ints if space is an issue. [Here is a very good SO answer that explains this topic in more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-con/981130#981130).

Comment: I believe that his use of Integer was for demonstrative purposes only. I believe that the real code uses an array of non-Integer custom class objects.

Comment: you are correct, i use my own object. and i can't understand how it can take so much space

Comment: Yeah, it's the reference size overhead that's getting you. If you are using Java 64bit you can also try -XX:+UseCompressedOops to help reduce the size of references.

Comment: CompressedOoops will roughly halve the size of the `Integer[]` array, but the `Integer` objects remain the same size.

Answer (score 4):

Lets assume that we are talking about a 32bit OpenJDK-based JVM.

- Each Integer object has 1 `int` field - occupying 4 bytes.
- Each Integer object has 2 header words - occupying 8 bytes.
- The granularity of allocation is (I believe) 2 words - 4 bytes of padding.
- The Integer[] has 1 reference for each array element / position - 4 bytes.

So the total is 20 bytes per array element.  20 x 30 x 1,000,000 = 600,000,000 Mbytes.  Now add the fact that the generational collector will allocate at least 3 object spaces of various sizes, and that could easily add up to 900+ Mbytes.

---

> how could i fix it ?

- Use `int[]` instead of `Integer`.
- If the `Integer` values mostly represent numbers in the range -128 to + 127, allocate them with `Integer.valueOf(int)`.  The JLS guarantees that `Integer` objects created that way will be shared.  (Note that when an `Integer` is created by auto-boxing, then JLS stipulates that `valueOf` is used.  So, in fact, this "fix" has already been applied in your example.)
- If your `Integer` values mostly come from a larger but still small domain, consider implementing your own cache for sharing `Integer` objects.

---

> My question was about Integer as an example, in my program i use my own object that only holds an array of bytes (max size of 4). when i create it, it takes a lot more then 4 bytes on the memory.

Yes, it will do.

Let's assume your class is defined like this:

```
public class MyInt {
    private byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
}
```

Each `MyInt` will occupy:

- `MyInt` header words - 8 bytes
- `MyInt.bytes` field - 4 byte
- Padding - 4 bytes
- Header words for the byte array - 12 bytes
- Array content - 4 bytes

Now add the space taken by the `MyInt` reference:

- Reference to each `MyInt` - 4 bytes

Grand total - 36 bytes per `MyInt` element of a `MyInt[]`.

Compare that with 20 bytes per `Integer` element of an `Integer[]` or 4 bytes per `int` element of an `int[]`.

---

How to fix that case?

Well an array of 4 bytes contains 32 bits of data.  That can be encoded as `int`.  So the fix is the same as before.  Use an `int[]` instead of a `MyInt[]`, or (possibly) adapt one of the other ideas discussed above.

Alternatively, make the heap larger, or use a database or something like that so that the data doesn't need to be held in RAM.

Comment: My question was about Integer as an example, in my program i use my own object that only holds an array of bytes (max size of 4).
when i create it, it takes a lot more then 4 bytes on the memory.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer` is an object which will take more than 4 bytes. How much more is implementation dependent. Do you really need `Integer`? The only benefit is that it can be `null`. Perhaps you could use a "sentinal value" instead; say, -1, or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should be using a database rather than a huge array, but if you must use a huge array of objects, have you tried increasing the Java memory size by using a the -Xms command line argument when running the Java application launcher?

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you are looking for but the optimal solution is to use a function instead of an array in this simple example.

```
static int index(int num) {
    return num;
}
```

If you have a more realistic example, there may be other optimisations you can use.