# Case classes memory consumption

Tags: scala, memory-management

I have the code that defines some entity structure, for example:

```
case class EntityDefinition(id: UUID,
                            name: String,
                            propertyDefinitions: Map[String, PropertyDefinition] = Map.empty[String, PropertyDefinition])
```

And i have the following code for entity:

```
case class Entity(entityDefinition: EntityDefinition, 
                  id: UUID, key: String, 
                  properties: Map[String, Property[Any]])
```

Will each entity take extra memory for storing it's entityDefinition instance? I intend to keep the number of EntityDefinitions very low, but each will occupy significant size.

So the question is whether to keep this structure for an entity, or to implement some kind of Reference that would get the entity definition from the cache on demand?

Comment: Why do you think case classes different from usual classes in this aspect? It will keep a reference. As long as there is more than 0 live references to the object, object itself will be kept in memory.

Comment: That what I was concerned about - whether to generate immutable case class Scala somehow copies the object :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *share* the entity definitions, then you only need to calculate one object reference per `Entity` for them. The size of an object reference is [specified by the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-co)