# Java Object Array null Element Memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory, jvm

Currently I'm using the following data structure:

```
MyObject[] arr = new MyObject[100]
```

now most of the fields in the Array are actually null (let's say 97%)

As far as I can see the JVM reserves for each field the required memory for one instance of `MyObject` so a lot of memory is reserved even though it is never really used.

Is there a way to save memory? Like only allocate the space for `MyObject` on demand? 
Is there a better data structure then just a simple array? (needs to be both mem efficient and fast)

Comment: The jvm reserves memory for MyObject references (most likely pointers). Those don't take much space.

Comment: you can use arraylist. you can add elements as many as you want(its capacity is dynamic).

Comment: I'm really thinking that why you are doing this much optimization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> As far as I can see the JVM reserves for each field the requiered memory for one instance of MyObject so a lot of memory is reserved even though it is never really used.

No, it doesn't. It reserves enough memory for 100 *object references*, not 100 instances of `MyObject`. An object reference is not big (32 or 64 bits, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981130/157247) for details). ASCII-art below.

Now, if you're bothered by even reserving 100 slots that are the size of an `int` or `long`, you could use `ArrayList` which will reallocate a backing array as necessary (but this can add to memory fragmentation), a `LinkedList` which doesn't use an array at all (but has higher memory overhead for the entries that it *does* have), or even a structure such as a `Map` that doesn't (necessarily) use arrays at all (but again has higher overhead per entry).

ASCII-art and details for the 100-place array:

So when you first create that array, here's what you have in memory:

```
+-----------+
| arr       |
+-----------+       +------------+
| reference |------>| MyObject[] |
+-----------+       +------------+
                    | null       |
                    | null       |
                    | null       |
                    | (96 more)  |
                    | null       |
                    +------------+
```

Then you assign an instance, say:

```
arr[1] = new MyObject();
```

That gives you

```
+-----------+
| arr       |
+-----------+       +------------+
| reference |------>| MyObject[] |
+-----------+       +------------+
                    | null       |     +-------------------+
                    | reference  |---->| MyObject instance |
                    | null       |     +-------------------+
                    | (96 more)  |     | someField         |
                    | null       |     | someOtherField    |
                    +------------+     | ...               |
                                       +-------------------+
```

...then maybe you add another:

```
+-----------+
| arr       |
+-----------+       +------------+
| reference |------>| MyObject[] |
+-----------+       +------------+
                    | null       |     +-------------------+
                    | reference  |---->| MyObject instance |
                    | reference  |--+  +-------------------+
                    | (96 more)  |  |  | someField         |
                    | null       |  |  | someOtherField    |
                    +------------+  |  | ...               |
                                    |  +-------------------+
                                    |
                                    |  +-------------------+
                                    +->| MyObject instance |
                                       +-------------------+
                                       | someField         |
                                       | someOtherField    |
                                       | ...               |
                                       +-------------------+
```

...and so on as you store more instances in the array.

Comment: @t-j-crowder, you said "** even a structure such as a Map that doesn't use arrays at all **". As far as I know any Map implementation in java use a backed array. for eg: HashMap and HashTable both use backend array to storing map entires. Is that true ?.

Comment: @RavinderReddy: A particular implementation may use one or more arrays. Or not. That's an implementation detail.

Comment: @Ravinder Reddy: `TreeMap`, for example, does not use an array.