# What is the memory usage of a reference to another object in java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, reference

If for example, I had a linked list of nodes. Each having a field referencing the next node. How much memory does this reference (not the next object) take?

E.g if I have:

```
Class Node
nextNode node;

public Node(node nextNode){
this.nextNode = nextNode;
}
```

Does the nextNode field take any memory? If I read correctly, the reference takes 4 bytes, but I'm unsure as I find conflicting information.
Thanks!

Comment: It isn't specified, but you can expect it to take 8-16 bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981073/how-big-is-an-object-reference-in-java-and-precisely-what-information-does-it-co

Comment: I think it usually takes twice as much as a pointer on your system.  So 64 bits on a 32 bit system, and 128 bits on a 64 bit system.  However 64 bit systems have a JVM flag to use (mostly) 32 bit pointers so you can reduce memory usage a lot with that flag.